# how to import and plot history of trades over tradingview charts?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have csv files with trades in format:
e;2023-01-03 09:59:00;16000.00
p;2023-01-03 10:18:00;b;32.86;1;100
e;2023-01-03 10:59:00;16014.75
e;2023-01-03 11:59:00;15978.50
p;2023-01-03 12:24:00;b;32.51;2;100
e;2023-01-03 12:59:00;15946.50

I want to plot Buy & Sell orders with a couple of corresponding data points over the chart at its specific entry/exit points. I have tried to use PineScript and anything I did would creates errors.

Is this even a good idea to use tradingview for such purpose? Could someone please give some code examples of how would it be done properly in versions 4 or 5?

All kind of errors with script not being able to compile due to constants etc

Comment: What did you find to be the best solution?  Any code sample you can share as an answer here to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `input.string()` for your data input.

I would structure your input in a way that it would be easy to parse.

Something like: `e;2023-01-03 09:59:00;16000.00|p;2023-01-03 10:18:00|`

So that, each trade is separated by '|'.

```
Trade 1: e;2023-01-03 09:59:00;16000.00

Trade 2: p;2023-01-03 10:18:00
```

And features of those individual trades are separated by ';'.

```
Trade 1:
Type: e
Date: 2023-01-03 09:59:00
Price: 16000.00
```

So, you would first use `str.split()` with `|` as delimeter and get an array of trades. Then for each trade, you would use `str.split()` with `;` as delimeter to get the details of that trade.

Comment: I can't change my input format. Also, not every string is a trade, but a supplemental information that also needs to be plotter. Big issue is what to use to plot those values over the chart properly. p;2023-01-03 10:18:00;b;32.86;1;100 means;
on the given date there was a Buy order @ price 32.68 for 100 shares and position # 1

Comment: You know your input format better than I do. So, you should be able to come up with a parser function similar to what I described. To display the trades, I would use `label`s.